# What objects can set a player color property/How does something use the player color property in LBP2?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

I am working on a level in LBP2 where automatically setting a unique color would be of benefit. I could've sworn I saw it somewhere but I can't remember where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hologram material (probably among other purchased materials) is modifiable based on player color and automatically inherits the closest related player by controls/controllinator/action.

For example, if player 1 hits a button tied to a hologram set to be player color, the hologram will take on that players color.